# Arranging letters with 2 conditions

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can 11 letters {a,b,c,d,e,f,x,x,x,y,y} be arranged so that every y must be between 2 X's(not necessarily adjacent)?

Ans:3 * 11c5 * 6!

I need explanation.

Comment: Please, write properly !

Comment: The only combinaison with $x$ and $y$ you can have is $xyxyx$. To me, there is $7!$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 11 positions to fill. Choose 6 of them in $\binom{11}{6}$ ways and fill the $a,b,c,d,e,f$ in them in $6!$ ways. In the remaining 5 positions, we place the $x,y$ in one of the three ways: $x y x y x$, $x y y x x$, $x x y y x$. Thus the number of ways is $3 \times 6! \times \binom{11}{6}$. Note that we do not mean that the $x, y$ are adjacent. They are in the remaining slots after filling the $a,b,c,d,e,f$. For instance $a x b c d e x f y y x $ is counted correctly.